# Entity framework- EF Code First Select foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Model:

```
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public long AddressId { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }

    public string Town { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext:

```
public class DataModelContext : DbContext
{
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; }
}
```

Using above code its creating this schema for DB.

```
Addresses          Users
-----------        -------
AddressId(PK)      UserId(PK)
Street             UserName 
Town               Password 
State  
Country 
User_UserId(FK)
```

Now i want to access User_UserId from Addresses table, but it not showing any property there. Its giving error "Address does not contain a definition for User_UserId.....

```
using (var db = new DataModelContext())
{
       db.Addresses.Select(x=>x.User_UserId).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Foreign-Key Association** instead of **independant association** while creating models. It means that, you must include a foreign key property in your model alongside with a corresponding Navigational Property. For example:

```
public class Address
{
    ...
    public int UserId {get; set;} //Foreign-Key property

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; } // Navigational Property  
    ...
}
```

Read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx) for more information.